# Hexadecimal numpad

Tags: input, keyboard, hex

The project I am currently working on requires a lot of hexadecimal numbers to be entered into the code.

I once saw a pic of an old keyboard with a hexadecimal numpad (has A-F letters on it also) replacing the normal numpad. Anyone know where I can get one of these?

Comment: Where were the alphabetic characters placed in relation to the numbers?  I'm curious...

Comment: It was two additional rows either above or below the normal numbers, hard to remember which.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IPv6 Buddy -keypad should work well for hexadecimal input.

http://www.ipv6buddy.com/

[image]

Comment: interesting, though I would still want the arithmetic function buttons as well.

Answer (score 5):

If you can get your hands on one of the [retired space shuttles](http://www.reddit.com/r/technology/comments/7slqt/space_shuttle_cockpit_pic/), they have one!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't the A-F keys be UNDER the 7-8-9 row?

Comment: @Outlaw Programmer, I dunno. Ask NASA. They probably ran a $10 million dollar usability study on why having A-F on the top was better. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I have an old [Heathkit](http://www.old-computers.com/museum/computer.asp?c=785&st=1) learning toy with a hex numpad because the only way to program it was to assemble code by hand (it came with a 6800 manual and some notepads) into the online monitor.  This was actually fun!

[image: Heathkit picture showing Hex-keypad]

Mine is missing the 'D' button however.

Comment: Looks like Arduino prototype. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Great idea with the programmable keypad. I think i am going to pick up one of these: [DX1 input system](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=dx1+input+system). Works for any reconfiguring I might want to do.

Comment: If it's a good idea, you could vote my answer up, or even mark it as the answer :) The pellets encourage good behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the one you're talking about? 
[funky http://www.cpmuseum.com/Exhibits/Apple%20Lane/7603/7603-0005/images/000%20Front%20View.jpg](http://www.cpmuseum.com/Exhibits/Apple%20Lane/7603/7603-0005/images/000%20Front%20View.jpg) 
While this has a lot of "gee whiz" appeal, I have to say:

You have two hands. Use them. A-F are all reachable with the left hand on a standard keyboard while your right hand is on the num-pad. Instead of putting muscle-memory time into some arcane Hex-pad, you'll be learning to touch-type with your left hand, which has application outside your current project.

Better yet, come up with a smarter way of getting the hex codes into your code. Write a script that extracts them from your data-source and into your code as symbolic variables... or whatever.

**EDIT**

Ok, I'll give you the benefit of the doubt. Lets assume you're working on a hardware project and need to provide a specialized interface for your user. Maybe a [programmable keypad](http://www.genovation.com/progkeypads.htm) would fit the bill?

Comment: I know that this is extremely old, but I just want to point out that I personally often type only with my left hand while my right hand remains on my mouse, A hexadecimal keypad would save a lot of time when typing a large amount of hexadecimal digits.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the specifics right now, but I'm pretty sure you can easily write a keyboard remapper.  You could remap the QWASDF keys to ABCDEF in order to type them more quickly.  That way you could use 2 hands to type. Or if you are in control of the program they are being typed into, you could just translate the keys in code on the fly.  You also might want to try out the [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=8be579aa-780d-4253-9e0a-e17e51db2223&DisplayLang=en)